# Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am using the below code to access the MS Access Database. But i got a error message Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.How can i solve this issue.

common.cs

```cs
public static bool DBConnectionStatus()
{
    try
    {
        string conString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=|DataDirectory|db_admin.mdb; Jet OLEDB:Database Password=admin";
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(conString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            return (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open);
        }
    }
    catch (OleDbException)
    {
        return false;
    }


protected void btn_general_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        bool state = common.DBConnectionStatus();
        if (state == true)
        {
            cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from tbl_admin");
            da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            
            da.Fill(ds); // Error Here 
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {

            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: The `using` will dispose/close the connection, so the method `DBConnectionStatus` is pointless.

Comment: One more thing is you have to assign the connection to command object.

Answer (score 0):

> I did suggest you to modify your code to something like this:

```
private DataTable YourData()  
{  
    string conString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=|DataDirectory|db_admin.mdb; Jet OLEDB:Database Password=admin";  
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();  
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString))  
    {  
        try  
        {  
            conn.Open();  
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_admin", conn);  
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;  

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);  
            adapter.Fill(ds);  

            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)  
            {  
                // do somethign here  
            }  
        }
        catch (Exception)  
        {
            /*Handle error*/  
        }  
    }  
    return ds.Tables[0];  
}
```

> And then:

```
protected void btn_general_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
     this.YourData(); // you will get the Data here. you can then use it the way you want it         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing a `Command` which you use to construct a `DataAdapter`, but both without setting the required `Connection` property:

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from tbl_admin"); // <-- no connectuion assigned
da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);  // <-- no connectuion assigned
```

So your exception is pretty self-explanatory.

One final note: `using` will `dispose`/`close` the `connection`, so the method `DBConnectionStatus` is pointless. So don't use it, instead use the `using` in in the first place:

```
try
{
    using(var con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    using(var da = new OleDbDataAdapter("elect * from tbl_admin", con))
    {
        var table = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(table); // note that you don't need to open the connection with DataAdapter.Fill
        if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e1)
{
    // don't catch an exception if you don't handle it in a useful way(at least loggging)
    throw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement you can also use SqlDataAdapter instand of ExecuteReader.

```
public void ReadMyData(string connectionString)
{
    string queryString = "SELECT OrderID, CustomerID FROM Orders";
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
        connection.Open();
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader.GetInt32(0) + ", " + reader.GetString(1));
        }
        // always call Close when done reading.
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```